# html form's action method is not taking to the file

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have an html form where there are input fields for username, password, confirm-password and email. When i submit the button which is input type="submit" it does not take me to the action method's file rather it refreshes the file. I also wrote javascript to stop refresh by e.preventDefault() but same thing is happening.

This is the stupid html.

```
    <div id="container">
        <form action="includes/register.inc.php" method="post" id="form-container" class="register-form">
            <h1 id="linklist">Register</h1>
            <div class="input-container">
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username">
                <i class="fas fa-user" id="username-logo"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="input-container">
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                <i class="fas fa-lock" id="password-logo"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="input-container">
                <input type="password" name="confirm_password" id="confirm-password" placeholder ="Confirm password">
                <i class="fas fa-lock" id="password-logo"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="input-container">
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                <i class="fas fa-envelope" id="email-logo"></i>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" name = 'register' class="submit" value="Register">
            <p id="login">
                Have an account? <a href="login.php">Log in</a>
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
```

This is the stupid extra javascript which didn't worked.

```
$(function() {
    $('.register-form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    })
});
```

This is the file where the form should take me.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    echo "Am i stupid";
}
else{
    header("location: ../register.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: try this one line after preventDefault `$(this).submit()`

Comment: Your input submit's name is `register` not `submit` so you would check `$_POST['register']` not `$_POST['submit']`

Comment: This code does submit to the ``includes/register.inc.php`` for me. Is there any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

- Input type submit has name: register .
- Then you only can check next parameters with `$_POST[..]`.

Parameters:

[image: parameters]